# Make a div start at the end of another div

Tags: html, css, grid

As you can see in the picture the grid I've design is partially covered by the navigation bar at the top. I'd like my grid starts when the navigation bar it finishes.I'm using cargo collective and the menu is pinned at the top of the page. Do you have any solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="TemporaryHome" rel="history" id="home">HOME</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="artista"> ARTISTƏ</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="gallery">GALLERY</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="news">NEWS</a>
  <a href="Coming-Very-Soon" rel="history" id="about">ABOUT US</a>
</div>
```

The grid (as I said is in another folder as I'm using cargo collective):

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="prova">1</div>
   <div class="prova">2</div>
   <div class="prova">3</div>
   <div class="prova">4</div>
   <div class="prova">5</div>
   <div class="prova">6</div>
   <div class="prova">7</div>
   <div class="prova">8</div>
   <div class="prova">9</div>
   <div class="prova">10</div>
   <div class="prova">11</div>
   <div class="prova">12</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.prova{
      border: 1px solid; 
}

 .wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
   grid-column: 3;
   grid-row: 2 / 4;
 }
 .wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
   grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
  width: 100%;
  background-color: none;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
}
```

[image: The grid is cut at the top]

Comment: i don't know cargo collective and I cannot see how the .wrapper and .navbar are placed on the page. If .navbar is above .wrapper and .navbar is absolutely positioned can you add a margin-top or padding-top to .wrapper the same height as the height of the .navbar?

Answer (score 0):

css starting from width 100% and below to be placed in what element? there is no initializer where to put it